# DHT11 returning incorrect values

Tags: sensors, temperature-sensor

I am trying to use DHT11 sensor with Arduino. But unfortunately it is returning following values:

Temperature = 1.00
Humidity = 2.00

My code is as follows:

```
#include <dht.h>
dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN 7

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
    Serial.print("Temperature = ");
    Serial.println(DHT.temperature);
    Serial.print("Humidity = ");
    Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Link to the library I am using is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1paTI5fzcHodno5azFOSVVDT0E/view)

I have connected +ve to 3.3 V
I have connected -ve to Ground
I have connected out to digital pin # 7

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Current temperature of the room otherwise is 34 degree celsius and 62% Humidity

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the **functions**:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#define DHT11_PIN 7
DHT dht(DHT11_PIN, DHT11);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    dht.begin();
}

void loop() {

    float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
    float temperature = dht.readTemperature();

   if (isnan(humidity) || isnan(temperature)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
      return;
    }

    Serial.print("Temperature = ");
    Serial.println(temperature);
    Serial.print("Humidity = ");
    Serial.println(humidity);

    delay(1000);
}
```

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: It seems that you are using a different library. Can you tell me which library are you using for this code?

Comment: I'm using the Adafruit DHT library, here https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library. I've been using it for more than a year; no complains.

Comment: Serial.begin(9600);  was missing so I added that in your code and I still get the same output as before.
Temperature 1 and Humidity 2

Comment: @Saad. I tested the same sketch on my *lab*. It works, but sometimes the DHT act *funny*. Check connections, place a 4.7K resistor between Vcc and Data Line.

Comment: Ahmm I am not quite good with circuits. So not sure if I am supposed to put one at both places or just use one resistor. And secondly I only have 10k resistors at the moment :O would they work?

Comment: It's a *pull-up resistor* You can use a 10K, as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: I have added pictures in the original question showing how i used resistor. Still getting same temperature and humidity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64109/discussion-between-look-alterno-and-saad-bashir).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a DHT11, DHT11 is blue, DHT21 is black, and DHT 22 is white.
It must be a DHT22 hence the wrong values.

EDIT : on your pictures the white case says AM2302, it's definitely a DHT22 the code must be adapted accordingly.

Comment: I had the reverse problem: I used a DHT11 (blue one) instead of a dht22 (white one). The value I got were in the 500`C for the temperature and the 1500% for humidity. Replacing the DHT11 by the DHT22 solve it.